# While PHP Loop inside Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(<?php echo json_encode($re=='reject'); ?>){
        //if response is reject
        document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById('onreject').style.display="block";
    }

    else if(<?php echo json_encode($re=='approve'); ?>){
        //if response is approve
        document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById('onapprove').style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('hide').style.display="block";
    }
</script>
```

I want this to be inside a while loop til `<?php $responseanswer = mysqli_fetch_array($result); ?>`how do i that?

Comment: `json_encode()` is not JavaScript encoding.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the first answer, here's one possible solution that doesn't involve switching back and forth between JavaScript and PHP too much.  I'm personally a fan of templating engines (such as [Smarty](http://smarty.net)), but this is my next preference (*all* the logic goes in the PHP code, the JavaScript at the end of the loop just does the display work for you).

```
<script>
<?php
while($responseanswer = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  // This is probably not how your code does it, but I don't know your table structure
  $re = $responseanswer[0];
  $div_to_show = "";

  // whether to show the element with ID "hide"
  $hide_display_style = 'none';

  // Decide now what divs we want visible and hidden
  if($re == 'reject') $div_to_show = 'onreject';
  else if($re == 'approve') $div_to_show = 'onapprove';
  else $hide_display_style='block';

  echo "document.getElementById('hide').style.display = '$hide_display_style';\n";
  if($div_to_show) {
    echo "document.getElementById('$div_to_show').style.display = 'block';\n";
  }
}
?>
</script>
```

Comment: hey..that's amazing..but the approve n reject are not working

Comment: People can't always respond within one minute.

Comment: I made a couple typos but it should be correct now.  However, since I don't know your whole application (but only what you've shown us), I can't possibly write something completely correct.  In particular, each iteration of the loop will try to change the value of the same divs, which can't possibly be what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

Anyway, combining JavaScript and PHP like this is not preferable in my opinion.

```
<?
 while($responseanswer = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
 if(<?php echo json_encode($re=='reject'); ?>){
     //if response is reject
     document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none"; 
     document.getElementById('onreject').style.display="block";
 }

 else if(<?php echo json_encode($re=='approve'); ?>){
     //if response is approve
     document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none"; 
     document.getElementById('onapprove').style.display = "block";
 }
 else
 {
     document.getElementById('hide').style.display="block";
 }
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, at the PHP side you already know what is going to be executed on the JavaScript side. Therefore, you are wasting bandwidth and loading time this way. At the client side, it will always say `if(true)` or `if(false)`. You could, using PHP, decide what to send to the client and what not to send.

Comment: Another reason why you shouldn't write it this way is that mixing inline PHP into JavaScript becomes more and more unreadable as your codebase grows.

Comment: Wrapping the JS in the PHP loop like this will repeat the entire if/else-if/else javascript block N times, one for each element of your fetch_array. Since each repeated block refers to the same 'hide', 'onreject', and 'onapprove' elements this wouldn't even do what you want. If you have 3 elements in the array [ 'reject', 'approve', 'neither' ] your 1st if-block through would set onreject to block, the 2nd would set onapprove to block, and 3rd would set hide to block, so all 3 elements would be visible. Remember: by the time the Javascript is executing the PHP just *does not exist* any more.

Comment: @stephne great explanation..that is exactly what is happening. cant u provide a better solution?

Comment: @sarthak I think you've been given enough suggestions to be able to solve this now.

Comment: @sarthak: my better solution would be what Steve Howard put in his answer (upvoted) - do all the logic in PHP to decide which lines of javascript to output to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ewww.  This makes it hard to read, I think a solution like this would be better.  (But not best).  Best would probably to have a js functions that knows how to handle what to hide and show as well, or adding styles within the tag elements themself or not outputting the id's explicitly.

Either way, this should be more readable, and will be easier to add additional elements;

```
<?php
    switch ($re) {
        case 'reject':
            $styles = array(
                'hide'      => 'none',
                'onreject'  => 'block',
                'onapprove' => 'none'
            );
            break;
        case 'approve':
            $styles = array(
                'hide'      => 'none',
                'onreject'  => 'none',
                'onapprove' => 'block'
            );
        default:
            $styles = array(
                'hide'      => 'block',
                'onreject'  => 'none',
                'onapprove' => 'none'
            );
    }

    foreach ($styles as $id => $value) {
        echo 'document.getElementById("' , $id, '").style.display="', $value, '";', PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Comment: @sarthak Why are you using JavaScript to hide the elements anyway? You could much easier decide the class name through PHP, and define the visibility using CSS.

Comment: approvedocument.getElementById("offbox").style.display="block";

approvedocument.getElementById("onreject").style.display="none";

approvedocument.getElementById("onapprove").style.display="none";

Comment: still...element is being displayed.

Comment: this is pseudo code -- so i just came up with it real fast.  There are missing commas.  You should get the general idea though.  Seperate your logic from your interface as much as possible ... it'll make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: You need to understand what you're trying to do before you post a million posts.  We're here to help you, not to do your job for you.  I fixed the edits but you should try to understand the problems we're trying to solve for you.  It seems you only care if it works ....